# Why my clear function with selected element does not work correctly?

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list

during working on  the project to school, i find a little problem, which i do not know remove.
Problem is in fuction clear_train. When i trying to remove 1. element, function return also my element(but empty).
Here is my source code where are definitions of all functions:
(in a_train.h are a declarations and descriptions of functions)

```
#include "a_train.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
struct car* add_car(struct car* first,const char* target) {
    struct car* adder = malloc(sizeof(struct car));
    struct car *current = first;
    strcpy (adder->value,target);
    adder->next=NULL;

   if(first == NULL){
        first =adder;}

    else{  
        while (current->next != NULL) {
            current = current->next;
            }
            current->next = adder;
            }      

    return  first ;
}

void print_train(struct car* first) {
    if (first!=NULL){
        while (first!=NULL){
            printf("%s\n",first->value);
            first=first->next;
        }
    }
    else printf("empty list\n");
}

void cancel_train(struct car* first) {
    while(first!=NULL){
        struct car* canceler = first->next;
        free(first);
        first=canceler;
    }
}


struct car* clear_train(struct car* first, const char* target) {
    if(first == NULL){
        return NULL;
    }else if (first->next==NULL){
            if(strcmp(first->value,target)==0){
                free(first);
                return NULL;
            }else return first;


    }

    struct car* prev_searcher =first;
    struct car* this_searcher =first;
    while (this_searcher!=NULL){
        if(strcmp(this_searcher->value,target)==0){
            prev_searcher->next=this_searcher->next;
            free(this_searcher);
        }
        prev_searcher=this_searcher;
        this_searcher=this_searcher->next;
    }

    return first;
}
```

here is the definition of linked list:

```
struct car {   
    char value[SIZE];
    struct car* next;
};
```

source code of main where i am calling functions:

```
int main(){
    struct car* train = NULL;
    train = add_car(train,"Presov");
    train = add_car(train,"Bratislava");
    train = add_car(train,"Levoca");
    train = add_car(train,"Spiska Nova Ves");
    train = add_car(train,"Bardejov");
    train = add_car(train,"Pichne");
    clear_train(train,"Presov");
    print_train(train);
    cancel_train(train);

    return 0;
}
```

And finally there is output:

```
            //there is empty node
Bratislava
Levoca
Spiska Nova Ves
Bardejov
Pichne
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are making things more difficult to remove a node from a linked list than it needs to be. While you are free to return and assign the head node each time `clear_train` is called, that's not really the way to do it.

Instead of passing a pointer-to-head (`first`) as the parameter to `clear_train`, pass the actual address of the head pointer, e.g.

```
clear_train(&train,"Presov");
```

That way you can manipulate the value (node) at that address directly. If the first node in the list is the one being delete, you simply update the node address held by the original pointer to the new first node and you are done.

Instead of trying to keep a previous, current and next node, simply use a pointer-to-pointer to current node. Then when the node containing `target` is found, you simply update the pointer at that address to the `->next` node and you are done. See [Linus on Understand Pointers](https://grisha.org/blog/2013/04/02/linus-on-understanding-pointers/)

That reduces your `clear_train` function to:

```
void clear_train (struct car **first, const char* target) {

    struct car **ppn = first;   /* pointer-to-pointer to first */
    struct car *pn = *first;    /* pointer-to-first */

    for (; pn; ppn = &pn->next, pn = pn->next) {    /* iterate, find target */
        if (strcmp (pn->value, target) == 0) {      /* if found */
            *ppn = pn->next;        /* set pointer at target address = next */
            free (pn);              /* free node contianing target */
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Much simpler than trying to test for different cases of where the node lies.

Answer (score 0):

In `clear_train`

when you find the car - you free the element and then you try to get to it again so the program will make you problem.
write like this

```
if(strcmp(this_searcher->value,target)==0){
        prev_searcher->next=this_searcher->next;
        free(this_searcher);
return prev_searcher}
```

Comment: Nope, still same result. And also yes, function search match at every element. There where is match, free them and connect to the next element.